# Cron doesn't insert record to database

Tags: permissions, php, cron

I have a file:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 michal michal 1679 Apr 24 06:55 acx.php
```

The owner file `acx.php` is user `michal`, so I create cron using:

```
sudo crontab -u michal -e
```

My cron:

```
*/10 * * * * php /var/www/html/cron/exchange/acx.php
```

In log cron I see:

```
Apr 25 04:10:01 savecoin CRON[9722]: (michal) CMD (php /var/www/html/cron/exchange/acx.php)
```

I change the permission file `acx.php` on `777`, but it did not help. When I run the cron manually, the data correctly saves to the database. I do not know what else I can change so that cron can write data to the database

I use php7.2, apache2 http server and MySQL database.

Comment: Have you tried to specify the path of the php executable ? e.g. `/usr/bin/php` instead of just `php` in the cron ?

Comment: Whether the result is the same if you run the job from the root's crontab (`sudo crontab -e`)? You can redirect the output to a log file, maybe there will find some clue ( `*/10 * * * *  php /var/www/html/cron/exchange/acx.php >> /path-to/log 2>&1`).

Comment: The permissions of the script has nothing to do with insertion of records in a database. Does the script update the database correctly when you run it from the command line?

Comment: @Ponsfrilus Change from `php` to `/usr/bin/php` it did not help. @pa4080 in new log file I see error: `PHP Warning:  include_once(../db.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/cron/exchange/acx.php on line 2
PHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening '../db.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/cron/exchange/acx.php on line 2
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Database' not found in /var/www/html/cron/exchange/acx.php on line 9`, when I run file acx.php using the command `php acx.php` then the script correctly save data to the database

Comment: I think the problem are the relative paths in your script. Try this: `*/10 * * * * cd /var/www/html/cron/exchange/ && php acx.php`